# Can't install karma through npm with node 0.10.15

Tags: node.js, npm, karma-runner

I'm trying to install karma by running

```
sudo npm install -g karma
```

The output I'm receiving is

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Running node 0.10.15 on OSX 10.8.4.

Any advice on things to try would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Installed successfully for me on 0.10.12 and OSX 10.8.4. I'll update to 0.10.15 and try again.

Comment: Probably dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called

Answer (score 1):

Got it working if anyone else has the same problem

```
sudo npm -g cache clean
```