# cordova installation issue on windows 10

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I have tried to install cordova globally on my machine using the command `npm install -v cordova`. I am trying to install cordova globally on my windows 10 machine. I have installed node version 6.2.2 and npm version 3.9.5 and it was working correctly.

But when in try to install the cordova globaly on machine using the command `npm install -g cordova` i am getting a mail like i attached. Please let me know the issue[image]

Comment: close all termials and try `npm install -g cordova` and let me know the result

Comment: Also, it is far easier to help if you copy the code into here rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @john i have tried the same but the same result getting as like in the image attached. FYI: i have download and install the node js from the link https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

Comment: @Mathew Bakaitis. What i have done is, i have installed the node js via the exe download from https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/ and after that just try npm install -g cordova. I am getting the error lie in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm cache clean` and then `npm install -g cordova`.

More about this:

- [cordova cli installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746052/cordova-cli-installation-error)
- [Cordova won't install on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555054/cordova-wont-install-on-windows-10)