# Error installing sqlite3 in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a problem installing package in node.js. My version of npm is 2.14.3 and I need to install sqlite3 package.
In my proyect path Im usign this command: "npm install sqlite3 --save" I have the next error:

> npm WARN package.json node-sqlite@1.0.1 No description npm WARN
>   package.json node-sqlite@1.0.1 No repository field. npm WARN
>   package.json node-sqlite@1.0.1 No README data npm WARN package.json
>   node-sqlite@1.0.1 No license field. /
>
> > sqlite3@3.1.8 install /home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3
> >     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403):
> >     https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.8/node-v46-linux-arm.tar.gz  node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.8 and
> >     node@4.1.0 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with
> >     node-gyp)  make: Entering directory
> >     '/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
> >     ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep
> >     Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3150000/sqlite3.c TOUCH
> >     Release/obj.target/deps/action_before_build.stamp CC(target)
> >     Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3150000/sqlite3.o
> >     Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3150000/sqlite3.c:199451:1: fatal
> >     error: opening dependency file
> >     ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3150000/sqlite3.o.d.raw:
> >     No such file or directory compilation terminated.
> >     deps/sqlite3.target.mk:120: recipe for target
> >     'Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3150000/sqlite3.o'
> >     failed make: ***
> >     [Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3150000/sqlite3.o]
> >     Error 1 make: Leaving directory
> >     '/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/build' gyp
> >     ERR! build error  gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code:
> >     2 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
> >     (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
> >     gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
> >     ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
> >     Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
> >     gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.21-v7+ gyp ERR! command
> >     "/usr/local/bin/node"
> >     "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
> >     "build" "--fallback-to-build"
> >     "--module=/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node"
> >     "--module_name=node_sqlite3"
> >     "--module_path=/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm"
> >     gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3
> >     gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3 gyp ERR! not ok 
> >     node-pre-gyp ERR! build error  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed
> >     to execute '/usr/local/bin/node
> >     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
> >     build --fallback-to-build
> >     --module=/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node
> >     --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm'
> >     (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
> >     (/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
> >     node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) node-pre-gyp
> >     ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7) node-pre-gyp
> >     ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
> >     node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> >     (internal/child_process.js:211:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux
> >     4.4.21-v7+ node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp"
> >     "install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
> >     /home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3 node-pre-gyp
> >     ERR! node -v v4.1.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.31
> >     node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok  Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node
> >     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
> >     build --fallback-to-build
> >     --module=/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node
> >     --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm'
> >     (1) npm ERR! Linux 4.4.21-v7+ npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node"
> >     "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "sqlite3" "--save" npm ERR! node v4.1.0
> >     npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.8
> >     install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` npm ERR! Exit
> >     status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.8 install script
> >     'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'. npm ERR! This is most
> >     likely a problem with the sqlite3 package, npm ERR! not with npm
> >     itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm
> >     ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build npm ERR! You can get
> >     their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlite3 npm ERR! There is
> >     likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! Please include the
> >     following file with any support request: npm ERR!
> >     /home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/npm-debug.log

If I try to execute my node.js program I have the next error:

> module.js:338 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module
>   '/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node'
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15) at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25) at Module.require
>   (module.js:365:17) at require (module.js:384:17) at Object.
>   (/home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:15)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:434:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:452:10) at Module.load (module.js:355:32) at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12) at Module.require
>   (module.js:365:17)

After update (npm install -g npm)

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
>   npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>   /usr/local/lib
>   └── npm@3.10.9 
>   npm ERR! Linux 4.4.21-v7+
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/ npm" "install"
>   "-g" "npm" npm ERR! node v4.1.0 npm ERR!  npm  v3.10.9 npm ERR! path
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
>   npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! syscall access
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' npm  ERR!     at Error (native) npm 
>   ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'] npm  ERR!   errno: -13, npm  ERR!
>   code: 'EACCES', npm  ERR!   syscall: 'access', npm  ERR!   path:
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' } npm  ERR!  npm ERR! Please try
>   running this command again as root/Administrator. npm  ERR! Please
>   include the following file with any support request: npm  ERR!
>   /home/pi/Desktop/node-sqlite_Sockets/npm-debug.log

Somebody know how to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Best regards.

Comment: check if sqlite3 supports your current nodejs version or not. this was my issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

have you installed sqlite3 before on another app? because your cached files could be corrupt. try to remove it from your cache with `npm cache clean sqlite3` or clean your whole cache with `npm cache clean` and run the install script again.

**Edit**: after you edited your question. it seems to be a permission error. Try running the npm update with `sudo npm install -g npm`

**Summary**: It was a problem with an old npm version. The update to a newer version solved it by running `sudo npm install -g npm`.

Comment: Chresse thanks for reply me :) I have done that you say me but I have the same error :S Can you think of anything else?

Comment: @Tecnico: have you successfull installed any other npm packages? otherwise try to update your npm with `npm install -g npm`

Comment: I can't. I have error. I update my question you can see.

Comment: @Tecnico: after your edit it seems like a permission error. run the update comand with sudo: `sudo npm install -g npm`

Comment: Solve! :) Thanks you very much!!

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me on Windows 10.

```
npm uninstall sqlite3
npm cache clean
npm install sqlite3
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to install it on Visual Studio Code terminal, and this solution worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! After uninstall sqlite3 and install again solved the problem.

Comment: Had to install latest python, not sure if that in conjunction with these instructions solved my problem too

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers in different stackoverflow threads worked for me.

I **deleted the cache**, **deleted the lock file**, installed **another version** of Node, **updated NPM**, etc., but none of them worked. Maybe my answer is off-topic, But if you just want to get the job done right now, you may be able to install the package you want with another tool like *yarn*:

```
yarn add <package>
```

is equivalent to

```
npm i --save <package>
```

For example, *SQLite3* and *Sequelize* could not be installed on my computer with *NPM*, which I could install with *Yarn*.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

- Previously app directory was `/My Files/TestApp` and it always threw that error.
- According to a suggestion on https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/1538, I moved the directory to another directory that doesn't have spaces in the path (`/FolderNameWithoutSpaces/TestApp`)
- And it worked

macOS Monterey v12.1
node version: v17.3.1
npm version:  v8.3.0

This may not be the exact answer to the above question, but for some people, it will work.

Comment: I had the same error, and it was fixed by removing the spaces on the directory name.

macOS Monterey (Apple M1 pro)

Comment: @Piumal1999 you are an absolute hero! thanks so much for your answer, i had tried everything previously but this finally fixed it for me. I shall never use spaces again!

Answer (score 2):

On linux you should check that you have python installed `python --version`, if not, you should check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245617/9477206

Answer (score 2):

Edit on 2022 : Please check the supported version of Node in sqlite npm documentation and use the supported Node version (mostly by downgrading using nvm)

For me the node verion is v16.x whereas the Sqlite max supported version is v12.x, so I downgraded and the issues went off!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- First, I had Visual C++ 2013 installed, then configured globally by running
  `npm config set msvs_version 2013 --global`
- Then I ran an installation of node-gyp by running `npm install node-gyp -g node-gyp`
- Finally, I installed Sqlite3 by running `npm install sqlite3`

Hope this helps someone as it had helped me