# Unable to set default python version to python3 in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying to set default python version to `python3` in `Ubuntu 16.04`. By default it is `python2` (2.7). I followed below steps :

```
update-alternatives --remove python /usr/bin/python2
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3
```

but I'm getting the following error for the second statement,

```
rejeesh@rejeesh-Vostro-1015:~$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3
update-alternatives: --install needs <link> <name> <path> <priority>

Use 'update-alternatives --help' for program usage information.
```

Comment: As stated in the warning, you are missing priority.

Comment: Take care not to remove Python 2.7 as it will cripple many facilities of you OS (from experience :( )

Comment: I made an edit to my answer in relation to your priority error.

Comment: A word of warning: It sounds like a bad idea to me to change `python` to Python 3. The default way to invoke scripts written in Python 2 is `python my-script-p2.py`, while it's `python3 my-script-p3.py`. I would expect many system scripts to rely on this.

Comment: For those who're interested in the topic I'd recommend to pay attention to the virtual environment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

My Ubuntu 18 LTS still uses Python 2.7 and, for example, I use the virtual environment for using Python 3.X and be up-to-date in my Django projects.

Comment: This link might have the answer ;) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63207387/10625611

Comment: Thansk @mr_azad comment, this is most likely the simplest way to make the change (on Ubuntu 18.04): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498264/482233

Answer (score 193, accepted):

EDIT:

I wrote this when I was young and naive, `update-alternatives` is the better way to do this. See @Pardhu's answer.

---

Outdated answer:

> Open your .bashrc file `nano ~/.bashrc`. Type `alias python=python3`
> on to a new line at the top of the file then save the file with ctrl+o
> and close the file with ctrl+x. Then, back at your command line type
> `source ~/.bashrc`. Now your alias should be permanent.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. Editing your bashrc does not do the same thing as update-alternatives. For example, scripts that begin with `#!/usr/bin/env python` will not use the version in bashrc. Please use @Pardhu's answer.

Comment: I wrote this answer a long time ago, and I am aware that update alternatives is not the same as changing bashrc. I can edit the answer if you'd like.

Comment: It is more of a warning to users with this question that changing the alias does not do the same thing. Up to you if you want to edit.

Comment: This is the only answer that helped me. I tried doing `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5.2`. `But I got: update-alternatives: --install needs <link> <name> <path> <priority> Use 'update-alternatives --help' for program usage information.`

Comment: @alexchenco you did not add priority at the end. right after python3.5.2 you should put something like 10

Comment: I did this and it broke things, like virtualenvs. This answer is creating more problems

Comment: Maybe it's better to use @Pardhu 's answer

Comment: We all were young. We needed the money.

Comment: It's good to do it for pip too. `alias pip=pip3`

Answer (score 575):

The second line mentioned can be changed to

```
[sudo] update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
```

This gives a priority of 10 for the path of `python3`.

The disadvantage of alternatively editing `.bashrc` is that using the commands with `sudo` will not work.

Comment: Good and easy way out.

Comment: Good and right to the point. " <priority>" in the error message already suggested it. BTW, "sudo" is typically needed to run this install command.

Comment: Like ywu said, I had to run "sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10"

Comment: This is the right way to do it for sure, but it's worth noting that changing the systemwide default is likely to break some things. For instance, I had to go and [apply a fix to terminator](https://askubuntu.com/a/869732/119639), which only works with python2.

Comment: Doesn't work completely -- after this command `python` runs `python3`, but `python-config` still runs `python2-config` and general breakage ensues

Comment: You can add the `alias sudo='sudo '` if you want to be able to run aliases as sudo.

Comment: what is python3 here?

Comment: whats that 10 doing there at the last of the command?

Comment: Type `which python3` to locate the path of python3 first. Then execute the `sudo update-alternatives --install <python path> python <python3 path> 10`

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python /usr/bin/python3.8 8` this worked for me

Comment: You can use aliases with sudo if you add the alias `alias sudo='sudo '` that is, an alias for sudo that is sudo with one blank space. The blank space after sudo allows you to use aliases from your `.bashrc` file with `sudo`.

Answer (score 98):

To change Python 3.6.8 as the default in Ubuntu 18.04 to Python 3.7.

Install Python 3.7

Steps to install Python3.7 and configure it as the default interpreter.

1. Install the python3.7 package using apt-get

   `sudo apt-get install python3.7`
2. Add Python3.6 & Python 3.7 to `update-alternatives`

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2
```

3. Update Python 3 to point to Python 3.7

   `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`
   Enter 2 for Python 3.7
4. Test the version of python

```
python3 --version
Python 3.7.1
```

Comment: You might want to include a warning that this can break packaged software. Python 3.6 is the distributed default and any bundled software packages will also assume this version.

Comment: Can I replace the python to version 3.7 instead of python3?

Comment: @Tim, what's the best way to take care of that?

Comment: @Wee Hong, yes you can. Instead of $ sudo update-alternative --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 ....
you just replace to $ sudo update-alterative --install /usr/bin/python python .....

and after:
sudo update-alternatives --config python.

Comment: Worked for me, but I realized that I had some old packages in the system that had python2 pre-remove scripts. So I couldn't deinstall them - had to switch back to python2 to be able to remove them...

Answer (score 73):

If you have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) you can install [`python-is-python3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python-is-python3):

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

which replaces the symlink in `/usr/bin/python` to point to `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Minor typo: Ubuntu Focal is 20.04, not 20.20

Comment: It's what I wanted, not just an alias. Thanks :)

Comment: Because this is about the latest distro, I'd suggest using `apt` instead of `apt-get` for `install` subcommand.

Answer (score 32):

To change to python3, you can use the following command in terminal `alias python=python3`.

Comment: But that only work for the current running process in terminal. If I close and open the terminal it will change back to python2.

Comment: @RejeeshChandran Look at Steampunkery answer

Answer (score 27):

**Update:**
Since Ubuntu 20.04, the python3 is the default version, but still, python is not registered as python3 by default. In order to make that happen, you can simply do :

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

For more information you can check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296790/python-is-python3-package-in-ubuntu-20-04-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-actually) out.
**Old way:**

Do

```
cd ~
gedit .bash_aliases
```

then write either

```
alias python=python3
```

or

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
```

Save the file, close the terminal and open it again.
You should be fine now! [Link](http://www.ubuntujourneyman.com/2011/05/24/100/)

Comment: sudo apt install python-is-python3 worked for me. +1

Answer (score 20):

A simple safe way would be to use an alias. Place this into ~/.bashrc file:
if you have gedit editor use

> gedit ~/.bashrc

to go into the bashrc file and then at the top of the bashrc file make the following change.

> alias python=python3

After adding the above in the file. run the below command

> source ~/.bash_aliases or source ~/.bashrc

example:

> $ python --version
>
> `Python 2.7.6`
>
> $ python3 --version
>
> `Python 3.4.3`
>
> $ alias python=python3
>
> $ python --version
>
> `Python 3.4.3`

Answer (score 19):

Just follow these steps to help change the default python to the newly upgrade python version. Worked well for me.

- `sudo apt-install python3.7` Install the latest version of python you want
- `cd /usr/bin`  Enter the root directory where python is installed
- `sudo unlink python` or `sudo unlink python3` . Unlink the current default python
- `sudo ln -sv /usr/bin/python3.7 python` Link the new downloaded python version
- `python --version` Check the new python version and you're good to go

Answer (score 13):

At First Install python3 and pip3

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip
```

then in your terminal run

```
alias python=python3
```

Check the version of python in your machine.

```
python --version
```

Answer (score 10):

As an added extra, you can add an alias for pip as well (in .bashrc or bash_aliases):

> alias pip='pip3'

You many find that a clean install of python3 actually points to python3.x so you may need:

> alias pip='pip3.6'
>   alias python='python3.6'

Answer (score 9):

This is a simple way that works for me.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

You could change `/usr/bin/python3` for your *path to python3* (or the version you want).

But keep in mind that `update-alternatives` is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 7):

get python path from

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

then set your python version

```
alias python="/usr/bin/python3"
```

Answer (score 6):

As it says, `update-alternatives --install` needs <link> <name> <path> and <priority> arguments.

You have link (`/usr/bin/python`), name (`python`), and path (`/usr/bin/python3`), you're missing priority.

`update-alternatives --help` says:

> <priority> is an integer; options with higher numbers have higher priority in automatic mode.

So just put a `100` or something at the end

Answer (score 4):

To change Python 3.6.8 as the default in Ubuntu 18.04 from Python 2.7 you can try the command line tool `update-alternatives`.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

If you get the error "no alternatives for python" then set up an alternative yourself with the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 2
```

Change the path `/usr/bin/python3` to your desired python version accordingly.

The last argument specified it priority means, if no manual alternative selection is made the alternative with the highest priority number will be set. In our case we have set a priority 2 for `/usr/bin/python3.6.8` and as a result the `/usr/bin/python3.6.8` was set as default python version automatically by update-alternatives command.

we can anytime switch between the above listed python alternative versions using below command and entering a selection number:

```
update-alternatives --config python
```

Answer (score 3):

For another non-invasive, current-user only approach:

```
# First, make $HOME/bin, which will be automatically added to user's PATH
mkdir -p ~/bin
# make link actual python binaries
ln -s $(which python3) python
ln -s $(which pip3) pip
```

`python` `pip` will be ready in a new shell.

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove `python-is-python2`:

```
sudo apt purge python-is-python2
```

And install `python-is-python3`:

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

It will automate the process of transition to new python3. Optionally you can get rid of remaining packages later:

```
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
```

Answer (score 3):

Set priority for default python in Linux terminal by adding this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 1
```

Here, we set `python3` to have priority 10 and `python2` to priority 1. This will make `python3` the default python. If you want Python2 as default then make a priority of python2 higher then python3

Answer (score 3):

```
       ~$ sudo apt-get install python3.9
/usr/bin$ cd /usr/bin
/usr/bin$ sudo unlink python3
/usr/bin$ sudo ln -sv /usr/bin/python3.9 python3
/usr/bin$ python3 --version
          Python 3.9.5
/usr/bin$ pip3 --version
          pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Comment: Finally the right and most effecient answer. 
In my case I wanted to change the base "python" and not "python3". So I did this sudo ln -sv /usr/bin/python3.7 python

Comment: @chainstair You should never manually modify anything in `/usr/bin`. The OS owns these files, and will get confused if somebody else messes with its little mind. In theory, an OS upgrade could lose any of your changes there.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3 #remove existing link
sudo ln /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3 # create a new link to the version of your choice
```

Comment: Seems like a bit of a sledgehammer solution, but I guess it'll work. Is is stable when updates are later installed or is this something you might have to redo after major updates? Mind you, this is probably exactly what I would do...

Answer (score 1):

The best way in ubuntu 18.04 which will work for all users is

```
sudo vim /etc/bash.bashrc
add lines
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

Save the changes and restart .

After restart what ever version of python 3 you have in the system along with python 2.7 will be taken as default. You could be more specific by saying the following in alias if you have multiple version of python 3.

```
sudo vim /etc/bash.bashrc
add lines
alias python=python3.6
alias pip=pip3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the priority argument

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 5
```

You can replace 5 with any priority you want. A higher priority alternative takes precedence over lower priority.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a possibility to use particular python version directly, I would go for it compared to `update-alternatives` and `alias` solution.

Ex.

```
python3.6 -m pip install pytest
ptyhon3.6 -m pytest test_sample.py
```

`-m` executes particular module for that particular python version.
The first line will install pytest for for that particular version and user in possible location `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Answer (score -1):

To change the default python version in linux use following command-

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python2
```

This will change default version to python3

To verify use command-

```
python --version
```

Comment: No. This will trick whomever needs `python2` with `python3`.

Answer (score -2):

**At first, Make sure Python3 is installed on your computer**

Go to your terminal and type:

`cd ~/`  to go to your home directory

If you didn't set up your `.bash_profile` yet, type `touch .bash_profile` to create your .bash_profile.

Or, type `open -e .bash_profile` to edit the file.

Copy and save `alias python=python3` in the .bash_profile.

Close and reopen your Terminal. Then type the following command to check if **Python3** is your default version now:

`python --version`

You should see **python 3.x.y** is your default version.

Cheers!

Comment: this method already described in preferred answer for this question. and your answer doesn't contributes anything.