# How can i remove python 2.7 as i already have 3.6.5 installed on ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu

i have both 2.7 as well as 3.6.5 installed , at first in ubuntu 18.04 the only python version available was 3.6 but after i installed numpy package, along with it 2.7 got installed as well and it turned into default.
Is there any solution so as to  make 3.6 the default one instead of 2.7??

Comment: I've recommended to not uninstall python2.7 from Ubuntu because Ubuntu's kernel uses it.

Comment: Open .bashrc file `nano ~/.bashrc`. Type `alias python=python3` on to a new line at the top of the file then save and close the file with `ctrl+o` and  `ctrl+x`.

Comment: @chinmayan you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to set default python version to python3 in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986507/unable-to-set-default-python-version-to-python3-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Okay will do,  @MaxvonHippel :)

Comment: @UTK007 if one of the answers solves the problem for you, please click the green check-mark to mark it as correct.

Comment: File Name to Write: /home/utkarsh/.bashrc                                       
^G Get Help         M-D DOS Format      M-A Append          M-B Backup File
^C Cancel           M-M Mac Format      M-P Prepend         ^T To Files............what do i need to select out of these??? @chinmayan

Answer (score 18):

Open .bashrc file `nano ~/.bashrc`. Type `alias python=python3` on to a new line at the top of the file then save and close the file with `ctrl+o` and `ctrl+x`.

Answer (score 4):

I set python 3 version as default using the following commands:

1. Check python version on terminal - `python --version`
2. Get root user privileges. On terminal type - `sudo su`
3. If needed write down the root user password.
4. Execute this command to switch to python 3.6. `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1`
5. Check python version - `python --version`
6. Write `exit` to exit the root mode