# (Python) ImportError: No module named irc.bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, twitch, twitch-api

```
  File "/home/pi/chatbot-python-sample/chatbot.py", line 12, in <module>
    import irc.bot
ImportError: No module named irc.bot
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I already installed irc and irc.bot

Comment: Can you tell me the command you used to install irc.bot and where you are running your code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have two or more versions of Python installed? Sometimes it could be the case.

Comment: It has already answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186129/how-can-i-remove-python-2-7-as-i-already-have-3-6-5-installed-on-ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186129/how-can-i-remove-python-2-7-as-i-already-have-3-6-5-installed-on-ubuntu)