# Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed Python 3.6.5 however when i type Python it shows Python 2.7.5.
Id like to use Python 3.

```
[aravind@aravind05 Python-3.6.5]$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5

[aravind@aravind05 Python-3.6.5]$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr 11 2018, 07:36:10)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I want to use Python 3

Comment: Is uninstalling Python 2.7.5 an option?

Comment: Don't change that! Setting `python` to Python 3 might break your system tools. Use `python3` or a virtual environment instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

Assuming you are on some *NIX OS using a bourne-shell-like shell, you could define an alias `alias python python3`.

You could also place a symlink named 'python', pointing to python3 into a directory that is listed earlier in your PATH:

```
# on debian-like distributions, the following directories should be reasonable
ln -s ~/.local/bin/python "$(which python3)"
# place the following line into your .bashrc
export PATH="~/.local/bin/python:$PATH"
```

Comment: @AfloroaieRobert That's not a very good answer. Aliases only affect the current shell, not any other (system) commands.

Comment: @melpomene, I've read the man page of the alias and you are right. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: [aravind@aravind05 /]$ alias python python3
bash: alias: python: not found
bash: alias: python3: not found

Comment: Dear All, My wifi is not working now, it was working fine till yesterday.

Comment: [aravind@aravind05 ~]$ nmcli general status
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN     
connected  full          enabled  enabled  enabled  disabled

Answer (score 0):

Like Klaus stated in a comment, changing your system Python version might break system stuff.

Instead, use virtualenv. [Here](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) is a very well explanation if you need help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have both versions of Python installed in your system, you need to direct your default Python to Python 3.x. You can do that by adding a few lines to your `.bashrc file`.

> Open your .bashrc file nano ~/.bashrc. Type alias python=python3 on to a new line at the top of the file then save the file with ctrl+o and close the file with ctrl+x. Then, back at your command line type source ~/.bashrc. Now your alias should be permanent.
>
> EDIT:
>
> For update alternatives, the priority is an integer. The priority represents which program should be the first used. This article sums it all up pretty well.

Here is the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41986843/4982185