# How can I specify the version of Python that is run from MATLAB's system function?

Tags: python, matlab, terminal

When I run the `pyversion` command in MATLAB, it returns 3.7 as the version number. But when I run `system('python --version')` it shows version 2.7. Is there any make the `system` function use 3.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is to call python as `python3` from `system`, rather than just python. The slightly more involved answer is to modify your system environment variables to either remove python 2.7 from the path, or move python3 higher up in the path so that it takes priority over python 2.7. You can find information on how to edit the system path [here](https://superuser.com/a/949577/917541).

EDIT: I just realised that I was assuming that you were using Windows. If you are using linux, you should use `update-alternatives` as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50331137/2837253).