# deployment with fabric issues

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

Hello I have trouble understanding packages manager such as `apt` `pip` `pip3`

I am trying to automate shell command with the use of `fabric3` library

I am following a book which tells me to write the following shell command `pip install fabric3`

My `fabfile.py` contains f-strings which are working on python3 only

when I do `pip list` I see `Fabric3 (1.14.post1)` so I am assuming that the package is successfully installed, yet when I run my `fab`, I get fab not found, and command line is telling me to `sudo apt install fabric`

But doing so is useless, because `fabric` is working only with `python2.7`

Basically I have thought of two possible solutions to my problem :
1- Trying to make the `fab` command to use `python3.6` instead of `python2.7` ? But I don't know how to do that ...
2- Deleting Fabric, and keeping Fabric3, but for some reason, I get this `'fab' not found` and I don't understand why

I have read the documentation but It is really obscur, I find no answer to my issue

Any help will be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

---

Update1:

So when I run `pip list`

```
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
attrs (17.4.0)
Automat (0.6.0)
bcrypt (3.1.7)
blinker (1.4)
certifi (2018.1.18)
cffi (1.13.2)
chardet (3.0.4)
click (6.7)
cloud-init (19.2)
colorama (0.3.7)
command-not-found (0.3)
configobj (5.0.6)
constantly (15.1.0)
cryptography (2.8)
distro-info (0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1)
Fabric3 (1.14.post1)
httplib2 (0.9.2)
hyperlink (17.3.1)
idna (2.6)
incremental (16.10.1)
Jinja2 (2.10)
jsonpatch (1.16)
jsonpointer (1.10)
jsonschema (2.6.0)
keyring (10.6.0)
keyrings.alt (3.0)
language-selector (0.1)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
netifaces (0.10.4)
oauthlib (2.0.6)
PAM (0.4.2)
paramiko (2.7.1)
pip (9.0.1)
pyasn1 (0.4.2)
pyasn1-modules (0.2.1)
pycparser (2.19)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pygobject (3.26.1)
PyJWT (1.5.3)
PyNaCl (1.3.0)
pyOpenSSL (17.5.0)
pyserial (3.4)
python-apt (1.6.4)
python-debian (0.1.32)
pyxdg (0.25)
PyYAML (3.12)
requests (2.18.4)
requests-unixsocket (0.1.5)
SecretStorage (2.3.1)
service-identity (16.0.0)
setuptools (39.0.1)
six (1.13.0)
ssh-import-id (5.7)
systemd-python (234)
Twisted (17.9.0)
ufw (0.36)
unattended-upgrades (0.1)
urllib3 (1.22)
wheel (0.30.0)
zope.interface (4.3.2)
```

Fabric3 is correctly installed

Then, I run this command to deploy my code on server :
`fab deploy:host=xxx@yyy`
where `xxx` is username
and `yyy` is domain name

I get the following error : `Command 'fab' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install fabric`

NOTE: I tried this command `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 10` 
found on this topic [Unable to set default python version to python3 in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986507/unable-to-set-default-python-version-to-python3-in-ubuntu/41986843)

and `which python` stills points to `/usr/bin/python`

I have found that I have `/usr/bin/python3.6`
Do you think if I manage to have the `which python` pointing to `/usr/bin/python3.6` my issue will be solved?

Comment: Run this: `which python` in your terminal to see which python version you are using. Also which OS - it sounds like linux?

Comment: Thanks for your answer
```which python``` points to ```/usr/bin/python```
Yes Linux

Comment: I did try a ```alias python=python3``` as I was trying to use ```python3``` as default python version

Comment: Could you update the post with the content of your script, and also how you run it.

Comment: Yes, it is updated

Comment: Could you try to start `python` from the terminal, then `import fabric`, does that work? If not I'm suspecting that the version of python that you start is not the correct.

Answer (score 1):

First of all fabric3 is unauthorized fork of fabric as stated here:

> unfortunately, the fabric3 entry on PyPI is an unauthorized fork of
>   Fabric 1.x which we do not control. Once modern Fabric gets up to 3.x,
>   4.x etc, we’ll likely continue distributing it via both fabric and fabric2 for convenience; there will never be any official fabric3,
>   fabric4 etc.
>
> In other words, fabric2 is purely there to help users of 1.x cross the
>   2.0 “major rewrite” barrier; future major versions will not be large rewrites and will only have small sets of backward incompatibilities.

[Source](http://www.fabfile.org/installing.html#fabric-and-fabric2-vs-fabric3)

1. Please be aware that you have two versions of Python installed on your system. `python2.7` and `python3.6`. When you call `pip install PACKAGE_NAME` it invokes by default the `pip` associated with `ptyhon2.7`. 
   To make sure which one is used type the following command `pip --version`. I guess it will return something like this `pip x.x.x from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`. Thus, you have to install `pip` for `python3.6` on your system. Please notice that you have then to use `pip3` instead of `pip`.
2. Uninstall fabri3 by executing the following command: `pip uninstall fabric3`
3. Install fabric2 using newly installed `pip3 install fabric>=2.4.0`
4. Run `fab deploy` from the directory where you have your deploy script. Don't forget to give the name `deploy` to your function which is responsible for the deploy like this:

```py
    from fabric import Connection as connection, task

    @task
    def deploy(ctx):
        with connection(host=host, user=user) as c:
             c.run('pwd')
```