# Is there a proper way to make web2py use Python3 instead of Python2?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, web2py

I have been using web2py with Python v2 for a couple of years, and now I would like to switch to Python 3 runtime, but I am not sure what is the proper way?

I am usually installing web2py using the installation script available from [here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/scripts/setup-web2py-nginx-uwsgi-ubuntu.sh), and it is running under **Ubuntu 18.04**.

```
djordje@vmi:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
djordje@vmi:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
djordje@vmi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I tried to set the default Python version to 3, as explained on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986507/unable-to-set-default-python-version-to-python3-in-ubuntu#:~:text=to%20go%20into%20the%20bashrc,file%20make%20the%20following%20change.&text=To%20change%20Python%203.6.8,Ubuntu%2018.04%20to%20Python%203.7.&text=Steps%20to%20install%20Python3.7,it%20as%20the%20default%20interpreter.&text=Save%20the%20file%2C%20close%20the%20terminal%20and%20open%20it%20again) using:

```
update-alternatives --remove python /usr/bin/python2
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
```

and it sets the default Python to v3, but even after rebooting the server - web2py still runs with Python v2.

```
Version
2.18.5-stable+timestamp.2019.04.08.04.22.03
(Running on nginx/1.14.0, Python 2.7.17)
```

Is there a recommended way to set web2py to run with Python 3 on Linux?

Comment: Have you been able to find a working solution?

Comment: So far, I haven't found a better solution than the one below. Also tried Tim Nyborg's recommendation, but it did not work every time.

Comment: Yes, it finally worked. Actually there were two installations of uwsgi on my server, in /usr/bin/ and /usr/local/bin. Since it was configured to use /usr/local/bin/uwsgi and I was not aware of this fact, it didn't work initially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of searching, it seems that I found something rather easy to implement, and is working in my case. Thanks to the following [link](https://gist.github.com/simoncoulton/2625954).

I installed the following:

```
apt install uwsgi-plugin-python3
```

and then I listed the installed plugins under the /usr/bin:

```
ls /usr/bin/uwsgi_python*
```

There were two: uwsgi_python3 and uwsgi_python36 so I used:

```
update-alternatives --set uwsgi /usr/bin/uwsgi_python36
```

And after rebooting the server, it worked:

```
2.18.5-stable+timestamp.2019.04.08.04.22.03
(Running on nginx/1.14.0, Python 3.6.9)
```

Maybe there is a better (preferred way), but I did not want to add a virtual environment, nor change the default OS Python version. This way, I just updated uwsgi runtime.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to switch between python 2 and 3 on our web2py servers by uninstalling one version's uwsgi pip package, installing the other, and restarting the service:

```
pip uninstall uwsgi
pip3 install uwsgi
service uwsgi restart
```