# I'm having trouble with compiling my py project using pycharm on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

this is my code :

```
    import math

q = input(print("enter the q"))
R = input(print("enter the R"))
n = 1
m = 1
dofpar = 2 * math.sin(m * 3.14159 / n)
U = (q ** 2 / (4 * 3.14159 * 8.8 * 10 ** (-12) * R)) * dofpar
for n in range(2, N):
    for m in range(1, n - 1):
        dofpar += 2 * math.sin(m * 3.14159 / n)
print(U)
```

and this is the error i face each time trying to compile :

```
/home/mohammad/PycharmProjects/untitled4/venv/bin/python /home/mohammad/PycharmProjects/p61h
/home/mohammad/PycharmProjects/untitled4/venv/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/home/mohammad/PycharmProjects/p61h'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Python interpreter is facing challenges in compiling your code, please make sure correct Python3 path is set in your system and not Python2. [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986507/unable-to-set-default-python-version-to-python3-in-ubuntu)