# Different directory using python3.8 instead of python3.7

Tags: python

I tried to open a file named (choony.py) from the terminal and I got an error.So,

this is what I typed in the terminal:

```
python3 choony.py
```

This is the error that I got

```
No such file or directory
```

I tried this in the terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

This is the result that I got

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

As you can see, python is running 3.7 
how can I make python 3.8 the defult.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Python3 is likely a symbolic link to the python3.7 binary.  Use ```which python3``` to determine where it's running from, go to that directory and ```ls -l python3```.  If, indeed, it is a symlink, remove it and replace it with a symlink to the python3.8 binary.

Comment: if you don't want to change the link (because another tool is normally controling this, hten just type)

`python3.8 choony.py`

Comment: Did you try these examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/41986843/7548672