# How to change default python version 2.7.18rc1 to 3.8.2 in Ubuntu 20.04 Lts

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I have two version of python 2.7.18rc1 and 3.8.2.If i type on my terminal `python -V` then it's open python 2.7.18rc1.I want it to change 3.8.2.How can i change this?

Comment: Does `python3` work? If so you can use that and don't have to worry about changing the default version.

Comment: maybe this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986507/unable-to-set-default-python-version-to-python3-in-ubuntu

Comment: Actually i'm learning flask,There i got an error .It's like `plabon@plabon-H110M-S2PV-DDR3:~/Desktop/flask$ python flaskblog.py
  File "flaskblog.py", line 40
    flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!','success')
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`That's why i tried to change this.

Comment: @PlabonKumer if you just replace `python` with `python3` it should fix your problem

Comment: Wow,Thank you so much.It's really fix now.

Comment: I would also recommend looking into virtual environments and/or Anaconda. https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual