# How do I install pip for python 3.8 on Ubuntu without changing any defaults?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install `pip` for `Python 3.8` on an `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`.

> I know this has been asked way too many times. But those questions do not concern keeping Ubuntu's defaults specifically. And the answers on those questions either don't work or go on to suggest something so drastic that it would break the system - e.g. change default `python3` version from `3.6` to `3.8`. You **SHOULDN'T**!

So far, I've been able to install `python3.8` successfully using the `PPA` - `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.8
```

Changed `python` command from `python2` to `python3.8` using `update-alternatives`:

```
update-alternatives --remove python /usr/bin/python2
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 10
```

Now, I get `python 3.8` when I run `python --version`:

> Python 3.8.5

The problem is, I still can't install `pip` for `Python 3.8`. 
If I try to install `python3-pip`, it installs `pip` for `Python 3.6` since `python3` still points to `python3.6.9`, and I intend to keep it that way. 
Try installing `python-pip`, and it will install `pip` for `Python 2.7`. 
Also there's no such package as `python3.8-pip`, so I can't install it like:

```
sudo apt install python3.8-pip
```

Output:

> E: Unable to locate package python3.8-pip 
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8-pip' 
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8-pip'

What can I do to install `pip` for `Python 3.8` on an Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

While we can use `pip` directly as a Python `module` (the recommended way):

```
python -m pip --version
```

This is how I installed it (so it can be called directly): 
Firstly, make sure that command `pip` is available and it isn't being used by `pip` for `Python 2.7`

```
sudo apt remove python-pip
```

Now if you write `pip` in the Terminal, you'll get that nothing is installed there:

```
pip --version
```

Output:

> Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo apt install python-pip

Install `python3.8` and setup up correct version on `python` command using `update-alternatives` (as done in the question).

Make sure, you have `python3-pip` installed: 
(This won't work without `python3-pip`. Although this will install `pip 9.0.1 from python 3.6`, we'll need it.)

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

This will install `pip 9.0.1` as `pip3`:

```
pip3 --version
```

Output:

> pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)

Now, to install `pip` for `Python 3.8`, I used `pip` by calling it as a `python module` (*ironic!*):

```
python -m pip install pip
```

Output:

> Collecting pip 
>    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/74/38c2410d688ac7b48afa07d413674afc1f903c1c1f854de51dc8eb2367a5/pip-20.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5MB) 
>     100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.5MB 288kB/s 
> Installing collected packages: pip 
> Successfully installed pip-20.2

It looks like, when I called `pip` (which was installed for Python 3.6, BTW) as a module of Python 3.8, and installed `pip`, it actually worked.

Now, make sure your `~/.local/bin` directory is set in `PATH` environment variable: 
Open `~/.bashrc` using your favourite editor (if you're using `zsh`, replace `.bashrc` with `.zshrc`)

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

And paste the following at the end of the file

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Finally, source your `.bashrc` (or restart the Terminal window):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now if you try running `pip` directly it'll give you the correct version:

```
pip --version
```

Output:

> pip 20.2 from /home/qumber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

*Sweet!*

Comment: runnning `sudo apt remove python-pip` on your system seems awfully risky. are you sure this won't break anything?

Comment: @Arne Removing `python-pip` is not risky at all. In fact Ubuntu does not ship with it. If you have it on your machine, it's probably because you installed it.

Comment: the slim ubuntu you get when you run `docker run -it ubuntu` also doesn't come with python, but if you delete it from your workstation's ubuntu you brick your machine. But if you're confident this won't happen with `python-pip`, delete away.

Comment: You can't delete `python`, obviously. Many core features depend on it in Ubuntu. Deleting `pip` however is different, since it's only a package manager.

Comment: unless a system utility uses it in code to do stuff like getting info on installed python packages. anyway, I was just chiming in to cast some doubt and say that "obviously" is a dangerous word. If your system came with `python-pip` pre-installed, please don't delete it and find a different way to install a recent one. if you installed it yourself, you're probably (not obviously) going to be fine removing it.

Comment: Surely, if you know that `python-pip` came preinstalled or was installed by any other program as a dependency, it's better to leave it as is.

Comment: In my case, `python3 -m pip list` works, but  `pip3` gives error. Should I accept it and use an alias or try to fix the issue `NameError: name '__main__' is not defined`

Comment: @Timo, This could be an issue with your `pip3` binary. Try upgrading or reinstalling it - `python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade`

Comment: Maybe your try is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main#comment102444289_51462434) changing  the `pip3` binary file.

Comment: @Timo, Sure. If that doesn't work, try reinstalling - `python -m pip uninstall pip` && `python -m pip uninstall pip`.

Answer (score 16):

As suggested in [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#get-pip-py) you can try with `get-pip.py`.

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3.8 get-pip.py
```

This will install pip as pip3.8.

**--- UPDATE**

Make sure you have `python3.8-distutils` installed to avoid below error

```
"No module named 'distutils.cmd'" error.
```

You can install `distutils` using:

```
sudo apt install python3.8-distutils
```

Comment: This looks like a very elegant solution if it sets the binary to `pip` command on 18.04.

Comment: @Qumber Then you can set alias in ~/.profile. it should be like `alias pip='pip3.8'`

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'

Comment: extremely elegant.   next command of `python3 -m pip install twine` worked like a charm.  Thank you for not making me think too hard.

Comment: @mirekphd `sudo apt install python3.8-distutils` first

Answer (score 7):

```
# install py3.8 and dependencies for the pip3 bootstrap script
add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt install -y python3.8 python3.8-distutils

# download and run the pip3 bootstrap script
cd /tmp && wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
    python3.8 /tmp/get-pip.py

# use pip py3.8 module to install python packages
python3.8 -m pip install numpy pandas
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be to install the pip that is in apt. `sudo apt install python3-pip`. The version of the pip that it installs is for all versions of Python not only for version 3.6 once installed you just need to update the pip with the command `python3.8 -m pip install pip` and he will be install the latest version of pip for Python.

I would not advise you to remove Python2 because it is an important module for the system you should just create a permanent "alias" in `.bashrc` for Python3 I did like this `alias python="python3.8`.

Comment: Setting up an alias would not help if you're trying to programmatically access `python3.8`/`pip 3. 8` using `command python`, if you're trying to install package from source  using `python setup.py build`, if you want to execute python by a different user e.g. `sudo python` and in many other cases.

Answer (score 2):

## Install python v3.8 as python

```
RUN apt update --fix-missing && \
apt install python3.8 -y && \
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 10
```

## Install pip for python 3.8

```
RUN apt install python3-pip -y && \
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this a couple days ago and I struggled a lot with it but I finally got it working, so I [wrote up what I did as a blog post](https://river.me/blog/change-pip-version/).

In the end I think I may have done mostly the same things as the above answer, but if you got lost following it, maybe my screenshots etc will help.

Here's the tl;dr of the process I did:

- Uninstall `python3-pip` & `python-pip` using `apt`
- Remove the old `pip` files from `/usr/local/bin`
- Reinstall `python3-pip` using `apt`
- Add `$HOME/.local/bin` to your `$PATH` (also restart your shell to make sure you did this right)

Answer (score -2):

On ubuntu server

```
sudo apt install python -y
```

For more information check this blog here.

https://teckresolve.com/install-python-packages-using-pip/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).