# Creating a docker container that runs Ubuntu with Python 3.6+ and Pip

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pip, window

I'm trying to install Python 3.6 or above with pip in an docker container that runs Ubuntu. I've tried quite a few things with no success

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt install python3.8 -y
RUN apt install pip

RUN pip install auto-sklearn
RUN pip install pandas

ADD test.py /

CMD [ "python", "./test.py" ]
```

This returns "Unable to locate package pip." I tried removing "apt install pip" incase Python 3.8 comes with it, but it gives me the error: "pip: not found."

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN install python3-pip
RUN pip install auto-sklearn
RUN pip install pandas

ADD test.py /

CMD [ "python", "./test.py" ]
```

This installs pip, but auto-sklearn requires Python version 3.6 or higher and this installs a lower version. Auto-sklearn requires Linux as well which is why I'm using "FROM ubuntu" rather than "FROM python" cause "FROM python" seems to build a container on whatever native OS is running on the computer building the container, which for me is Windows.

Comment: Make sure to use the right binaries, like `python3.8` and `pip3.8` or `python3,8 -m pip` all the time. You can also consider to use a newer Ubuntu version or a `python` baseimage.

Comment: @KlausD. My binaries look right, no? I also tried "Ubuntu:latest" and get the same errors and as I mentioned in the question I think the python base images boot using the same OS that my computer is running cause I get the auto-sklearn error exclusive to installing on non-Linux systems

Comment: No, you used the simple `pip` and `python` without version number multiple times.

Comment: @KlausD. okay, what exactly are you referring to when you say "binaries?"

Comment: @KlausD. I mispoke I guess I didn't try the top commands with "ubuntu:latest" because that seemed to work. If you want to post your answer and allow me to edit it and add the full Dockerfile I used, I'll give you the upvote and answer vote.

Answer (score 4):

I see two consecutive issues here, so let's address them accordingly:

### Issue 1: missing pip in the Ubuntu image

> This returns "Unable to locate package pip." I tried removing "apt install pip" incase Python 3.8 comes with it, but it gives me the error: "pip: not found."

That's right. If you inspect the contents of the `/usr/bin` directory of the pulled image, you will notice that there is no `pip` or `pip3` there. So `RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip` line in your Dockerfile does nothing. Even when `python3.6` gets installed in the container (after calling `apt install software-properties-common -y`), you do not get `pip` with it.

#### Solution: install pip

The following commands can be used to install `python3.6` binary and the corresponding `pip`:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3-pip
```

This installs both `python3.6` and `pip3` in the `/usr/bin` directory of your `ubuntu:18/04` container.

### Issue 2: auto-sklearn requires python >= 3.7

Even if you manage to get both `python3.6` and `pip` for `python3.6`, installation of `auto-sklearn` might still fail with the following error:

```
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.7 required.
```

This is because some of the dependencies (e.g. `ConfigSpace` package) require python version >= 3.7.

#### Solution:

This answer explains how to install `pip` for `python3.8` on Ubuntu: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63207387/15043192

You can follow it or get both `pip` and `python3.8` installed using the following sequence:

##### Install python3.8:

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt update
RUN apt install python3.8
```

##### Install python3.6 and pip for python3.6

```
RUN apt install python3-pip
```

Now if you execute `python3.6 -m pip --version` in the container, you would get something like (the version of `pip` might be different):

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

##### Install pip for python3.8

**Note:** here we use previously installed `pip` for `python3.6` to install `pip` for `python3.8`. Do not ask me why :-)

```
RUN python3.8 -m pip install pip --upgrade
```

##### Install auto-sklearn

```
RUN python3.8 -m pip install auto-sklearn
```

**Note:** the command above might also install `pandas` package among other dependencies of `auto-sklearn`.

#### Create a symbolic link to python3.8

This would change the default

```
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
```

Now if you execute `python -m pip --version` in the container, you would get something like (the version of `pip` might be different):

```
pip 21.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

### Grand finale:

In the end, your Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt update
RUN apt install python3.8
RUN apt install python3-pip
RUN python3.8 -m pip install auto-sklearn
RUN python3.8 -m pip install pandas
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python

ADD test.py /

CMD [ "python", "./test.py" ]
```

### NB

To avoid messing around with different versions of `python` and `pip`, you might want to have a look into [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments).

Comment: `ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127`