# create the python soft link fails

Tags: python

I have multiple Python versions, and thus also include multiple Python binary executables.

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

shows the python environments in my ubuntu 18.04

```
/usr/bin/python   /usr/bin/python2.7           /usr/bin/python2-pbr     /usr/bin/python3    /usr/bin/python3.5m  /usr/bin/python3.6-config  /usr/bin/python3.6m-config  /usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python2-jsonschema  /usr/bin/python2-wsdump  /usr/bin/python3.5  /usr/bin/python3.6   /usr/bin/python3.6m        /usr/bin/python3-config     /usr/bin/python3m-config
```

in order to satisfy the PyFlink requirement regarding the Python environment version, i have to choose to soft link python to point to your python3 interpreter:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python
```

however when I use the command, it tells me

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'python': File exists
```

so i wonder do I need to delete the /usr/bin/python first and then use the command to create the soft link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to set default python version to python3 in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986507/unable-to-set-default-python-version-to-python3-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't seem to work out to satisfy the PyFlink requirement, that is why I need to try this

Answer (score 4):

Command `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python` creates link `./python` pointing to `/usr/bin/python3`. You probably executed it multiple times so `./python` already exists. You could overwrite it by providing `-f` flag to `ln`.

You **definitely** should not delete `/usr/bin/python`.

The whole idea with manually creating links to Python interpreter to install a package seems very weird. I suggest one of the following options:

- just use the full path to the interpreter: `/usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install <package>`; if the package adds any scripts globally usable from command line, like `pyspark`, they will be installed with hashbang pointing to the interpreter you installed them with
- use a virtual environment: `/usr/bin/python3.6 -m venv ~/.env-py36; source ~/.env-py36/bin/activate; python -m pip install <package>`
- use something like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)