# Raspberry pi Package Easyimap not found

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run a python script that uses easyimap to send and recive mails. The script works fine on windows. I want to run it 24/7, but don't want to leave my pc on all the time. A PI would be a perfect solution for that. On the Pi I installed python with

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

which worked fine and python was installed. I then installed pip3 with

```
sudo apt-get install pip3
```

which worked fine as well. I then installed easyimap with

```
sudo pip3 install easyimap
```

also ran fine and told me it was installed. When i tried running my code with

```
python main.py
```

I got the error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import easyimap
ImportError: No module named easyimap
```

I also installed easyimap-python which didn't help. Any suggestions I could try?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/easyimap/

Comment: Did you try `python3 main.py` ?

Comment: check `python -V` - many Linux systems may have already installed `Python` and it can be `Python2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Furas, most of Linux system still have by default `python2` so running in terminal `python` only calls for `python2`. If you want to keep working with `python3`, you will need to set the default python version to `python3`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50331137/4244780) for correct way. To summarize it, you will need to:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
```

This way you won't have to call for `python3` in terminal, only `python` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

It worked the way Iron Fist said in his comment.

```
python3 main.py
```

worked fine.