# update pip to be consistent with python in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-20.04

I have `python 3.8` as the default install with `ubuntu 20.04`.

I have upgraded to `python 3.11`.

However, if i do `pip3 --version` is see this:

```
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

In windows i just do `pip install <package>` and i want to achieve the same level of simplicity in ubuntu.

How to get this to upgrade too (python 3.11) or whatever the latest version of python is in Ubuntu ?

Comment: you can use `python3.11 -m pip install <package>`

Comment: to echo @sahasrara62, I __only__ ever use `pip` via `python -m`. I find there are just too many chances for things to be pointing to an unexpected environment otherwise.

Comment: @sahasrara62,  this is what i currently do.  But i just want pip to point to the latest version.  I dont care for previous (legacy) versions. Hence the specific question.

Comment: @JonSG,   i hear what you say, but i remove previous (legacy) environments from the system.

Comment: @D.L `alias pip=python3.11 -m pip` add this in `~/.bashrc` and then do `source ~/.bashrc` , then you can use pip directly

Comment: How exactly did you "upgrade" to Python 3.11? Do you mean you installed it in parallel? Using Apt? From the regular repos? How did you configure your shell to prefer 3.11?

Comment: @tripleee,  yes, that is correct.

Comment: How did you configure your shell to prefer 3.11?

Comment: @sahasrara62,  i came across this method, but it means that if an upgrade is done, then the user needs to remember to upgrade the alias. Whereas the question requires the latest version (so `max(version)`), if such exists.

Comment: it still work with ubuntu upgrade

Comment: @tripleee,  i followed a guide like this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986507/unable-to-set-default-python-version-to-python3-in-ubuntu).

Comment: https://river.me/blog/change-pip-version/ is definitely confused but the stuff near the end is potentially useful.