# Get "pip2: not found" error in google colab

Tags: python, linux, ssh, pip, google-colaboratory

I want to install youtube uploader in google colab and i must run this code on colab cell:

```
#@title <<---- Run this cell to install dependencies
!git clone https://github.com/BoostUpStation/youtube-up.git
!cd youtube-up
!python youtube-up/setup.py
```

**but when i run this code i get this error:**

```
Cloning into 'youtube-up'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 94, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (43/43), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
remote: Total 94 (delta 39), reused 26 (delta 26), pack-reused 51
Unpacking objects: 100% (94/94), 8.20 MiB | 7.55 MiB/s, done.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python2.7 is already the newest version (2.7.18-1~20.04.3).
python2.7 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python3-pip

E: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate
sh: 1: pip2: not found
sh: 1: pip2: not found
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Looks like your default Python is 2.7. Switch to python3 ASAP.

Comment: @n.m. I'm an absolute beginner - please guide me thoroughly and provide the required command

Comment: I don't know what a colab cell is, it it's something like Debian or Ubuntu then you do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50331137/775806). Alternatively, use a [virtual environment](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+virtual+environment+python3).

Comment: The `setup.py` file in the cloned file tries to install various things...
`os.system('sudo apt-get install python2.7')`
`os.system('sudo apt-get install python-pip')`
`os.system('pip2 install --upgrade google-api-python-client')`
`os.system('pip2 install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2')`

It wants Python 2 which is not the Colab environment.