# Getting syntax error while using virtualenv package in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04, apt

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 in VMware virtual environment. When I try to install virtualenv, I am facing issues.

What I did:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip

sudo pip3 install virtualenv

virtualenv --version
```

The last command is showing this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sbedanabett/.local/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in <module>
    from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch
  File "/home/sbedanabett/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli
  File "/home/sbedanabett/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv/run/__init__.py", line 70
    raise RuntimeError(f"failed to find interpreter for {discover}")
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This seems because it is using Python2 interpreter. But I have changed my default interpreter to be Python3, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41986507/12357035). So I am clueless why this error.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.2
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.12
```

Comment: Using f-strings requires at least Python 3.6.

Comment: Then how to install correct version of virtualenv? (py3.5 compliant one)

Comment: Probably should have used askubuntu. Here's a similar post over there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get

Comment: for older version you can try this doc -- https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/legacy/installation.html

Comment: Still using Ubuntu 16.04 seems like a very dubious decision. This LTS release was end-of-lifed in 2021, at which point it stopped receiving any security updates etc.

Comment: @tripleee I can't update it at my will :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install an older version of virtualenv you try this command

For example to install 16.7.9

```
pip install https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tarball/16.7.9
```

To install in local

```
pip install --user https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tarball/16.7.9
```

and while running the command line for `virtualenv` use `python -m`

Example

```
python -m virtualenv --version
```

Comment: Nothing related to `virtualenv` is running.. Not even `virtualenv --version`.

Comment: I noticed that, I changed my answer