# Installing sqlite3 for nodejs

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-modules

Sqlite3 failed to install in nodejs

tried build from source as well , still not luck

> sqlite3@4.1.0 install .../node_modules/sqlite3
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
npm WARN auto_home@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing sqlite3 in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461439/error-installing-sqlite3-in-node-js)

Answer (score 3):

Try running the command after cleaning the `npm` `cache`

```
npm cache clean
```

If cleaning cache didn't work , upgrade your `npm`

```
 npm install -g npm
```

If there is any permission issue on upgrading add `sudo`

```
 sudo  npm install -g npm
```

reinstall `node-gyp`

```
npm install  -g node-gyp
```

finally, install `sqlite3`

```
npm install --save sqlite3
```

Answer (score 2):

install `sqlite3@4.1.1` instead.

I discovered this while following the issue https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/1246#issuecomment-561942175