# npm not running on Windows

Tags: windows, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install some packages using node but getting the following error:

```
 npm update check failed                  
 Try running with sudo or get access                 
 to the local update config store via         
 sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\DELL\.config
```

I have checked the read/write permissions to the specified folder and since I am a windows user I can't use `sudo`

Please help me out

Comment: `node -version` ?

Comment: Version is 8.9.4 @NiVeR

Comment: In windows, you can open a cmd with elevated privileges by right clicking `cmd` and `Run as administrator`. Try to execute the command on that command prompt.

Comment: It says: 'npm ERR! cb() never called!'
'npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>'

Comment: try `npm cache clean` with admin cmd

Comment: Its again showing same error, even when used with --force

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called

Comment: I did have a look, nothing worked

Comment: Last try: reinstall.