# Node error npm ERR! cb() never called

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When I am running the command `npm install npm@latest -g`
I am getting below error :-

```
npm WARN tar zlib error: unexpected end of file
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-10T03_25_52_880Z-debug.log
```

i googled it and tried so many things,nothing worked.

Comment: Try it `npm i -g npm`

Comment: The issue and workaround is discussed here https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19353

Comment: i had fixed same issue.  see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467848/npm-err-cb-never-called-error-when-trying-to-run-npm-install-command/58089750#58089750

Comment: In my case, it `npm cache verify` really worked. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61177561/6332074)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Use `npm ci` (Credits to [Justin Dehorty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12649786/justin-dehorty), see answer below)

**Old Answer**

To anyone stumbling upon this question, if you are facing the same error message on `npm install`, then `npm install --no-package-lock` solved it for me.

As suggested in the referenced [Github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19353) in Mohit Mutha's comment above, this is especially true if the command is ran in a CI/CD pipeline, or in my case, in Docker.

**EDIT:** Reason being is that the `package-lock.json` file already exists in your Docker image or CI pipeline

[Full details](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19353#issuecomment-367329967)

Comment: Confirming positive use of the flag on gitlab's pipeline for an ng v6 project.

Comment: in my case ( jenkins CI ), workspace was corrupted. cleaning the workspace helped.

Comment: People should know what they are disabling when calling `--no-package-lock`, don't you think?

Comment: "The --no-package-lock argument will prevent npm from creating a package-lock.json file. When running with package-lock's disabled npm will not automatically prune your node modules when installing." [Source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install)

Comment: One of the reasons for this issue is that you have package-lock.json file in your project directory. So, you may have to delete the package-lock.json file from the directory and then run the `npm install` command. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: DUDE, i could put million vote ups for this answer. You saved me a lot of time. Thanks!!!

Comment: Version 7.x.x of npm doesn't have the `--no-package-lock` option.

Comment: Was happening to me inside docker, weird thing was that on my machine with a newer version of docker everything was building smoothly, but on the server with a slightly outdated docker the build was failing with this error. package-lock.json didn't get cached, it was pulled from the github repo. Running `npm cache clean --force` before `npm install` fixed the issue just fine :)

Comment: We have a Gitlab CI and confirm this works.

Answer (score 12):

Our team encountered this error in our CI pipeline. However, the top answer of using `--no-package-lock` actually causes npm to also *not* use a present package-lock.json, which is definitely not the desired behavior for CI. Instead, using `npm ci` is now the recommended way to install in CI since it will use the existing package-lock (and nothing else).

Answer (score 6):

Solved by running

```
sudo npm cache clean --force
```

and after that deleting package-lock.json and node_modules

and then performing

```
npm install
```

Comment: Run the following command which solved my issue --- npm install --no-package-lock

Answer (score 0):

FYI I have gone through DOZENS of these responses for the exact same ask posted here again and again in SO. I think most of responses are valid. But in my case the actual issue was the CORPORATE PROXY not npm itself.

In my Dockerifle I had to explicitly add `http-proxy` and `https-proxy` to my npm config prior to running the `npm install` and it worked. FYI you need to tell npm config about your proxy or it wont download dependencies and this is what was throwing the `cb() never called` error - this works in both local (terminal) and docker containers.

```
...
RUN npm config set http-proxy http://mycompanyproxy.mycompany.com:8099
RUN npm config set https-proxy http://mycompanyproxy.mycompany.com:8099
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server"]
```