# Angular 6: npm ERR! cb() never called when installing angular cdk

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, npm-install

I am installing angular material  here is what I have done

Angular material successfull installed by the following command

```
   1.npm install --save @angular/material
```

Angula CDK fail to install by using the following command

```
  1.npm install --save @angular/cdk
```

I get the following error  in cmd:

```
npm WARN tar zlib error: unexpected end of file
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bonge\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-25T17_44_24_771Z-debug.log
```

Fo reference I never had this problem, this happend after I uninstalled the cdk and angular material so now I am trying to install it again ,

what do I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Just a comment: it is way easier to install material by running `ng add @angular/material`. It does all the dirty job for you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After googling  here is the solution i found

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way to resolve is update the npm version and install again.

npm install -g npm

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I installed it by excluding package-lock.json using below command

```
npm i --save @angular/cdk --no-package-lock
```

OR manually deleting package-lock.json

Answer (score 1):

Since NPM 6 you can do [clean install](https://betterprogramming.pub/npm-ci-vs-npm-install-which-should-you-use-in-your-node-js-projects-51e07cb71e26).

```
npm clean-install
```

That would try to remove the node modules folder and safely install the packages by checking the package-lock.json.

P.S. If that fails for some reason, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66798207/5935112) for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem is due to space not enough in the disk. So I cleaned up some space. Problem get solved.

Comment: i had fixed same issue.  see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467848/npm-err-cb-never-called-error-when-trying-to-run-npm-install-command/58089750#58089750

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. (cb() never called!). In my case folder has not read/write permission. Check your folder permission assign read/write permission to fix the issue.