# cannot create a new react project using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to create a new react project with create-react-app but each time it fails because of this error.......

I am using `npm` version `6.3.0` and `node` version `10.8.0`

I don't know what to do............

Creating a new React app in `C:\Users\Demonblade\Desktop\test`.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Demonblade\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-09T15_27_48_357Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting test / from C:\Users\Demonblade\Desktop
Done.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm ERR cb() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called)

Comment: Have you found the error? I have the same problem....

Answer (score 0):

Use `npx` (it comes with `npm` 5.2+).

From the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app):

> You’ll need to have Node >= 6 and npm >= 5.2 on your machine. To
>   create a project, run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```