# Npm-Typescript installation

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install

Tried to run ">npm install" in command line but ı got error like this cb() never called

I tried;

> npm cache clear --force

but it didnt work

also ı tried to install typescript like this

> npm install -g typescript

but same error occured

```
npm -v :6.4.1

node -v:10.15.0

npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\KAL-MET KALİBRASYON\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-443b24ed\bin\tsc'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\KAL-MET KALİBRASYON\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-443b24ed\bin\tsserver'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\KAL-MET KALİBRASYON\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-443b24ed\lib\cancellationToken.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\KAL-MET KALİBRASYON\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-443b24ed\lib\cs\diagnosticMessages.generated.json'

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\KAL-MET KALİBRASYON\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-24T08_36_15_783Z-debug.log

C:\Users\KAL-MET KALİBRASYON>
```

Comment: Check this answer https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/261 its help for you.

Comment: ı have tried but same error occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the name of the computer does not consist of characters.
It was me too.
Create a new user, but the username should be in English (not İ)
You will see that the user you just created is running npm install -g typescript with cmd

Comment: An better answer should be flagging this question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called.

Comment: I haven't marked the davi as necessary because the issue is caused by a slightly different usage username