# npm -g and --save-dev using

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, nodemon

When I use `>npm install -g nodemon` or `typescript`, I got "cb() never called" error.

I cant use -g, in Visual Studio code terminal, I can install typescript like this:

```
>npm install --save-dev typescript
```

but -g got same error in there again.

error pic link: https://ibb.co/L5wkbVX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Npm-Typescript installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54342624/npm-typescript-installation)

Comment: ı am in trouble with "cb() never called" and npm install -g

Comment: try to type in `npm -v` in the console, what does it output?

Comment: >npm -v : 6.4.1