# npm ERR! cb() in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

I'm currently running a node project in Jenkins and this is the error I'm getting.

```
Node Version
v10.15.0
NPM Version
6.4.1
Installing dependencies
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2019-02-18T06_02_02_727Z-debug.log
```

The Jenkins server has a node `10.15.0` installed and npm `6.4.1`.

This is my build script:

```
echo "Node Version"
node --version
echo "NPM Version"
npm --version

echo "Installing dependencies"
npm install
```

I saw from other thread in StackOverflow [npm ERR cb() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called)
that this can resolve by adding `engines` in package.json

I already tried adding this

```
"engines": {
 "node": "10.15.0"
}
```

but still no luck.

Comment: Did you try running `sudo npm cache verify` too before `npm install`?

Comment: Yup I'm getting 

Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache):
Content verified: 2022 (35313958 bytes)
Content garbage-collected: 2 (61930 bytes)
Index entries: 2022
Finished in 2.494s

I'm still getting the error cb()

Comment: Any solution?? I am also getting the same error