# npm ERR! cb() never called in windows10

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, error-handling

I was trying to run `npm install` inside the project folder but every time there is this error showing `npm cb() never called`.

I am using node version 10.16.2 and npm version 6.9.0 in windows 10

I have tried npm cache clean --force but that didn't help

> ```
> E:\contribution\contribute-to-open-source>npm install
> npm ERR! cb() never called!
>
> npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
> npm ERR! <https://npm.community>
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR! C:\Users\papun\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-10T03_51_20_512Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Check the answer out, might help. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15483897/6082280). Also since u are using npm 6^ you would need **cache clean** with force flag `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: I already tried that but the problem was not solved

Comment: @richard937, did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 35):

I had the same problems and lost hours trying to solve it :(.

But then i found out that my firm has installed some new kind of firewall ***with self signed certificate.***

Quick solution was:

```
npm config set strict-ssl=false
```

After that everything started working without 'npm cb() never called' errors

Comment: Thank you so much! It took me almost two days to find out what the issue is

Comment: Worked for me as well. Cheers!

Comment: Saved me hours of debugging!

Answer (score 5):

I had faced the same issue, and i spend days to get a solution for the issue. In the end, i figured it out and it was an issue with my network.

Please verify your network connection and proxy settings.

In my case, I was using corporate proxy using a script. When i opened the pac file and get the proxy from there ( take XXX:XXX from the line return "PROXY XXX:XXX;";) and added to npm config proxy setting (npm config set proxy XXX:XXX), it started working and got resolved.

Answer (score 5):

run this all issue will be solved..

```
 npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

Comment: Not if you're not on Windows! Maybe worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

try to set your proxy using the commands

- npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port
- npm config set https-proxy https://proxy_host:port

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted all the node_modules, package-lock.json but still it was not working. For me the reason was, there were some modules that required relogin to install.

So, I deleted my node_modules, build and package-lock.json. and opened command prompt in admin mode.

Then went to the specific project path and logged-in to the components that require credentials.

```
1. npm login (root path of your react app)
2. type username as "<xxxxx>"
3. type password as "<yyyyy>" (won't be visible on console)
4. type email as "<zzzz>@<aaa>.com"
5. npm i
6. npm run build
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem I deleted that file from

```
C:\Users\Harshk1311\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs
```

And problem solved

- Double Check file name in terminal where error occured  and delete file
- i.e C:\Users\Harshk1311\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-10T03_51_20_512Z-debug.log
- Delete 2019-08-10T03_51_20_512Z-debug.log ***only*** this file .

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason that solved the problem in my case:

Missing [MS VC Redistributable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist). For example if you are on a fresh new PC. In this case you could download the e.g. `VC_redist.x64.exe` and install it. You may need to restart the terminal before e.g. executing `npm i` again.

> The Visual C++ Redistributable installs Microsoft C and C++ (MSVC) runtime libraries. These libraries are required by many applications built by using Microsoft C and C++ tools.