# error cb() never called! - error while doing npm install

Tags: angular, npm, installation, node-modules

I am trying to install node modules in my angular project. But while doing **npm install** I get the following error

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/aino/.npm/_logs/2020-02-18T06_45_41_169Z-debug.log
```

And the error log is as follows

```
10005 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json shallow-clone@3.0.1
10006 silly decomposeActions fetch clone-deep@4.0.1
10007 silly decomposeActions extract clone-deep@4.0.1
10008 silly decomposeActions preinstall clone-deep@4.0.1
10009 silly decomposeActions build clone-deep@4.0.1
10010 silly decomposeActions install clone-deep@4.0.1
10011 silly decomposeActions postinstall clone-deep@4.0.1
10012 silly decomposeActions finalize clone-deep@4.0.1
10013 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json clone-deep@4.0.1
10014 silly decomposeActions fetch sass-loader@7.2.0
10015 silly decomposeActions extract sass-loader@7.2.0
10016 silly decomposeActions preinstall sass-loader@7.2.0
10017 silly decomposeActions build sass-loader@7.2.0
10018 silly decomposeActions install sass-loader@7.2.0
10019 silly decomposeActions postinstall sass-loader@7.2.0
.....
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case ( jenkins CI ), workspace was corrupted. cleaning the workspace helped.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was because of a connection problem.

So try to check your connection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).