# Npm/Vue creating a new project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I ran `npm i -g @vue/cli`. Then I tried to create a new project with `vue create test`, but I keep getting this error:

> NPM ERR! *cb() never called!*
>
> NPM ERR! *This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error
> at:* npm ERR!     *https://npm.community*
>
> NPM ERR! * A complete log of this run can be found in:* npm ERR!
> *C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-22T11_49_02_861Z-debug.log*
>
> ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR cb() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean the cache.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```