# I am trying to install node locally following error occurs. I tried reinstalling node several times but still it shows error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

I get this error when I try to install node

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-29T13_30_35_085Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Can you post what commands you are using to install node?

Comment: What’s in the log file? What stage in the node install process are you at? I’m confused: are you installing node as you state, or are you running npm or create-react-app or ...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR cb() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called)

Answer (score 0):

1. try this first before installing node.

   ```
    sudo npm cache verify

    sudo npm cache clean --force
   ```
2. After installing verify your installation:

   > node --version

Answer (score 0):

several things you can try are following

```
sudo npm cache clean --force
```

trying changing ownership of npm and try npm latest

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
npm install -g npm@latest
```

give it a try by clearing up the proxy, maybe you're behind proxy

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

*Lately i would like to recommend you to use the ***NVM package***. it is not the solution to your answer directly but its a great way to manage and have different node/npm environments*
https://davidwalsh.name/nvm