# Unable to install expo-cli due to socket timeout error

Tags: expo

[image]

This is the error that I get while installing the expo-cli.
Is there any way that I could try to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

Please update your npm first:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

after that

```
npm install --global expo-cli
```

Please let us know if you encounter further errors in the installation. Thanks

Comment: Now it shows , there's an error with npm itself and npm cb() never called

Comment: try npm cache clean --force

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called

Comment: code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'   Now it has this , I've been trying to install it for the past three days and I don't even know what's wrong!

Comment: Nothing is working thank you anyway I'll try using yarn

Comment: My installation worked after installing the latest.  Thanks.