# npm error : cb() never called, what should I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package

Hi everyone.

I've got an error from npm everytime I try to install pacakges.
I got this error :

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>
```

I know there's already a topic about my problem but I really tried every solution I could find and not a single one works. I uninstall and reinstall node multiple times, cleaned my cache but I can do nothing !

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "discord.js": "^12.4.0",
    "howlongtobeat": "^1.2.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Can somebody help me, I don't know what to do, I cannot install a single package ...

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you have `npm` as dependency in the project?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know but if I delete this package from my package.json, I still got the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR cb() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called)

Comment: Thanks for the link but this is the very first post I saw and I did everything in this one and it doesn't work, I don't know where the error come from ..

Comment: I also have a lot a warning before : tar EPERM: operation not permitted , open 'C:\Users\prevo\Desktop\coding_projects\BarkBot\node_modules\.staging\npm-38d46a69\node_modules\retry\equation.gif' and I don't know why I have this kind of thing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending hours on many recommendations that did not work. I finally got `npx create-react-app` running by doing the following:

1. Uninstall npm by running the following code at your command prompt:

   ```
   npm uninstall -g create-react-app
   ```
2. Increase timeout by changing/adding this line in your *.npmrc* file:

   ```
   timeout=60000;
   prefer-offline=true;
   ```

   Your *.npmrc* file can be found in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` (windows)

   Then RESTART your PC
3. Disable your antivirus (as *@Antoine* said)
4. Run the following at the command prompt

   ```
   npm clean cache --force
   npm install create-react-app
   npx create-react-app my-app
   ```

   where `my-app` is the name of your project

**NOTE**: I am not using any proxy.

Answer (score 5):

Just run:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
npm install --global npm
```

The command lines are self explanatory. One needs to clear (clean) the cache and upgrade `npm`. After which, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I manage to solve my problem by disabling my Antivirus, I don't know why ...

Answer (score 0):

On our local machine it worked, on Azure Pipelines the mentioned error showed up.

**Our solution:**
Add the 'npmAuthenticate' task before the npm ci command.

[> official description of the task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem in internal company project. I was able to reproduce the error and solve it by running `npm install --no-package-lock` but while running in the jenkins pipeline, the error was not solved.
I managed to solve it by disabling the proxies as below:

```
 sh """
        proxy='' \
        https_proxy='' \
        http_proxy='' \
        npm install
        npm run test
    """
```