# I've been trying to create a react app but I keep getting this error: "npm ERR! cb() never called!"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

this is the problem

> HP@DESKTOP-1HP83V8 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Web-Development (master)
> $ npx create-react-app my-app
>
> Creating a new React app in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Web-Development\my-app.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
> Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> npm ERR! cb() never called!
>
> npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
> npm ERR!     https://npm.community
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-20T11_50_51_060Z-debug.log
>
> Aborting installation.
> npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts >cra-template has failed.

Comment: Try deleting the package-lock.json and the node_modules folder and do a `npm install`

Answer (score 11):

I've encountered this multiple times.

First I would suggest that you run `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` since the global version isn't supported anymore.

Then try `npx create-react-app my-app` again.

If that does not work, try to run:

`npm init`

`npm install create-react-app`

`npx create-react-app my-app`

The steps above have solved the issue for me a couple of times

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect and reconnect to your source of internet (WIFI).
After that, run `npm cache verify`
Next you will want to run: `rerun npx create`

Comment: This sort of did it for me. I think my Wifi is unstable as I kept getting download error while downloading Node Windows Installer from my browser. I restarted my PC instead, and it worked somehow lol

Comment: Thus great Remondo, Great feedback

Answer (score 2):

Working Solution: thanks to idkwhatsgoingon's answer.

`create-react-app` does not work globally

1. npm uninstall -g create-react-app
2. npm install create-react-app
3. create-react-app app01

Answer (score 1):

try this command first:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and create your react app again.

Comment: What npm and node version do you have? node -v

Comment: This question may help you .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called

Comment: 6.14.8. i've installed it successfully, but will it still give me the same problem when next i try to install it?

Comment: Can you try this command instead then, from the docs: sudo npm cache verify

Comment: Worked like charm.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error .Here these things i did to solve it

1. I ran npm cache clean --force
2. after again npx create-react-app project name

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of these, it did not work. But I restarted the computer and it started working ! So after clearing the cache etc, might be be worth restarting the machine  ( Windows 10 )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to install netlify-cli.
Here are two things I did to solve it:

1. I deleted some files to clear up disk space
2. Since my npm version is 6.0+, I ran "sudo npm cache verify"

Answer (score 0):

Add the line

```
timeout=60000
```

to your `.npmrc` config file (create it at `~/.npmrc` if it doesn't exist)
then run `npx create-react-app project-name` should be successful. At least it was in my case. (I had *code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT* before)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing yarn. I did this and immediately fixed my issues.

```
npm install --global yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

first and foremost uninstall create-react-app by
`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
then
`npm cache clean -f` 
then
`npx create-react-app app-name`

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I run `npm cache verify`

After this command, I run `sudo apt install rerun`

Then I run the command `rerun npx create-react-app <app-name>`

It worked like magic