# creating next app with: npx create-next-app giving me error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a next app using the following `CLI` command: `npx create-next-app` and after entering my app name it gives me the following error:
[image]

Note that I have previously created a next app using the exact same method and it did work just as intented without any errors.

Comment: Hi Daniel, you can take a look in a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930058/ive-been-trying-to-create-a-react-app-but-i-keep-getting-this-error-npm-err

Comment: @Pitter hey thank you, the first answer in that link worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I honestly dont know why, but running `npm init` and `npm i create-nuxt-app` worked for me.

*Edit*: the problem can be with globally installed package, try running `npm uninstall -g create-nuxt-app` if answer above didnt help.