# what's mean npm error cb() in react application

Tags: reactjs

I tried to create a new react application.
I checked there are node and npm witht he last version, but when i try to run the following command
npx create-react-app project-name
then i faced with the following error.

can any one to help me what is the problem?

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\EiS User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-30T12_04_06_813Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting myweb/ from C:\Users\EiS User\Desktop\React_App
Done.
```

I tried many ways like run the following command

npm cache clean --force

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called)  related question. Which version of npm and node are you using?

Comment: for node : v14.15.1
for npm 6.14.9

Comment: @Mosen - Are you able to find the solution for that? Im also facing the same issue with v14.15.3 & 6.14.9

Comment: If you see there is an space between EIS and User in the following path:

C:\Users\EiS User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-30T12_04_06_813Z-debug.log

Justi tried to manage this space, then NPM worked. That was strange REALLY.