# Node error npm ERR! cb() never called when using npm install in an Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm

When I cloned an Angular 11 project from git and ran `npm install`, I got the below error:

```
npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/something/.npm/_logs/2021-06-26T17_17_38_979Z-debug.log
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04.2 and and node 14.17.1 and npm 6.14.13.

So far, I have tried uninstalling and installing node and npm again and running these commands but none of them work:

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm install --no-package-lock`

And there's also no node_modules and package-lock.json in the project I cloned. So deleting them doesn't work either (because they don't exist).

Comment: Please try `sudo npm cache verify` and let me know what is the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR cb() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called)

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
npx npmc@latest install
```