# Failed to create react app using "npx create-react-app signup_react"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Unfortunately, I failed to create the react app projects using

```
npx create-react-app signup_react
```

But I had made various projects using this same command. I need help to solve this issue and the error is given below,

```
Creating a new React app in /media/imdadul/PERSONAL/Professional Works/React_Projects/signup_react.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/imdadul/.npm/_logs/2021-07-09T16_19_45_838Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting signup_react/ from /media/imdadul/PERSONAL/Professional Works/React_Projects
Done.
```

**N.B.:** Please concern above error and help me who have knowledge about this, advanced thanks.

**npm version:** 7.9.0

**node version:** v15.14.0

Below is given the screenshot of this problem,
[image]

Comment: What is your version of ```npm```?

Comment: npm version: 7.9.0

Comment: And ```Node.js```?

Comment: node version: v15.14.0

Comment: Run `npm cache clean`

Comment: @SarwarAhmed, already I run it but it's not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest `Node.js`, then
try `npm install -g npm` & `npm cache clean`

More here:
[npm ERR cb() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called)

Answer (score 0):

@Alex, please concern here,
After updating it's changed the version of `npm_version: 7.19.1`
I have done what you have said but I can run `npm cache clean` run this command and it shows another error is given below,

```
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues
npm ERR! by treating integrity mismatches as cache misses.  As a result,
npm ERR! data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid.  If you
npm ERR! want to make sure everything is consistent, use `npm cache verify`
npm ERR! instead.  Deleting the cache can only make npm go slower, and is
npm ERR! not likely to correct any problems you may be encountering!
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer,
npm ERR! or race conditions that depend on the timing of writing to an empty
npm ERR! cache, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a
npm ERR! temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command
npm ERR! with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-07-09T17_26_16_921Z-debug.log
```

And now it's showing another error using `npx create-react-app signup_react` command and it's given below,

```
Missing dependencies in package.json
```

**Please concern above explanation of error**

Comment: `npm cache clean` command doesn't work. It says `If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.`  Try this `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: @SarwarAhmed it solved by uninstalling the node and npm then reinstall it. Thanks for your comments and help me.