# How can I make nodejs to start working again?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start

I've been using npm for a while to do a project with angular, but 3 days ago my windows so updated and since then the npm it's not working at all.
I try to run

`npm install`

The terminal shows this:

`npm ERR cb() never called!`

`This is an error with npm itself`

After this I tried to unistall and reinstall npm, to clean the cache,
`npm cache clan --force` ,but nothing seems to work at all.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15483897/14994086)

Comment: always save your source code and files for any project in github so you have ability to retrieve back any version of any file ... I cut a new git branch daily sometime when working on especially challenging problems in addition to several times per day saving files I edit using a simple git commit ... code revision is a critical skill for all developers and its never too early to start

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the npm version:

```sh
node -v
npm -v
```

and then if it doesn't work try updating npm:

```sh
npm install -g npm
```

and if *that* doesn't work then ***finally*** try [downloading it](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) from the website :)