# NPM install is crashing with error "ERR! cb() never called!"

Tags: npm, npm-install, google-cloud-build

We are periodically seeing builds fail within our cloud build process with the following error:

> docker.io/library/node:14 npm ERR! cb() never called!
>
> npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error
> at: npm ERR!     https://npm.community

Steps from build configuration:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    id: 'fetch'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        # convert the shallow clone to regular one
        git fetch --unshallow --no-tags
    waitFor: ['-']

  - name: 'node:14'
    id: 'npm-install'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        npm ci --unsafe-perm
    env:
      - 'CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=0'
      - 'CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=/cypress_cache'
    waitFor: ['fetch']
```

Any thoughts on things to try or to remediate this issue?

*EDIT*: All packages are installed from npm.

Comment: What hosts the npm registry, from where the packages are installed?

Comment: Does this happen only occasionally? Are your npm and Node versions compatible? This is old but may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called?rq=1

Comment: @MilanTenk all packages are from npmjs.

Comment: @JavierA it happens only occasionally. Yes node / npm version are compatabile as this is the official node:14 docker container

Comment: Isn't there maybe a company proxy or policy, that somehow sporadically blocks the downloading of a package?

Comment: @MilanTenk Shouldn't be proxy related. Fresh vm, fresh image and crashes maybe 1 in 20 times?

Comment: I had a very similar issue in a company environment. In my case it was actually reproducable on developer PC-s as well, if all the cache-es were properly cleaned. (All the cache-es cleaned means in this context followning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69310464/npm-install-always-uses-artifactory-registry-and-ignores-npmrc-file/69324487#69324487).
After a lot of meetings with different supports we actually did not make it, to fix the issue, as a workaround we built in a retry logic: if the `npm install` fails, try it again. This was stable enough.

Comment: Are you still experiencing the same issue? Did you try the @MilanTenk approach? It seems a good idea.

Comment: @drauedo no we haven't automatically built in a retry step. Essentially what we are doing is manually restarting the build when this happens.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by `@Milan Tenk` a good approach would be to implement a retry logic in your build by wrapping your command in a bash script.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts) are some examples on how you can modify you yaml file to a run bash scripts in Cloud Build:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'bash'
  args: ['./retryPolicy.bash']
```

If bash is not the default entrypoint:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['tools/retryPolicy.sh','--foo']
```

And [here](https://gist.github.com/dublx/e99ea94858c07d2ca6de) is an example of a retry logic implementation in bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

function myFunction() {
    myCommand
    return $?
}

retry=0
maxRetries=5
retryInterval=15
until [ ${retry} -ge ${maxRetries} ]
do
    myFunction && break
    retry=$[${retry}+1]
    echo "Retrying [${retry}/${maxRetries}] in ${retryInterval}(s) "
    sleep ${retryInterval}
done

if [ ${retry} -ge ${maxRetries} ]; then
  echo "Failed after ${maxRetries} attempts!"
  exit 1
fi
```

Please let me know if that approach worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

See NPM CLI WiKi:
[https://github.com/npm/cli/wiki/%22cb()-never-called%3F-Exit-handler-never-called%3F-I'm-having-the-same-problem!%22](https://github.com/npm/cli/wiki/%22cb()-never-called%3F-Exit-handler-never-called%3F-I%27m-having-the-same-problem!%22)

Sadly, there's never a straightforward answer.

However, many people seem to suggest deleting the `node_modules` folder in your project and also running the command `npm cache clean -force`.

For me it did not work - so I copied a `node_modules` folder from a PC, which could run `npm install` without having the error.
This at least allowed to use `npm install` without errors and build the project again.