# npm install always uses artifactory registry and ignores .npmrc file

Tags: npm

My .npmrc file previously contained `registry=https://company.jfrog.io` so upon `npm install` this registry was used. Now I want to use the public registry for my personal project, but even though I delete the .npmrc file and even create one at the root of my project containing the public registry, this custom registry is always used to install dependencies!

When i run `npm config ls -l` it displays `registry = "https://registry.npmjs.com/"` . But when i remove the lockfile and `npm install`, it still uses the artifactory registry!

How can I just use the public npm registry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change from one registry to an other you need to make sure, that you do following things:

- Check the current registry with `npm config list` command. The command should be called from the root directory of the project, as a local `.npmrc` can overwrite the `registry` settings. If the listed `registry` entry is not ok, please update the global and/or the local `.npmrc` file.
- Delete `node_modules` in your project.
- Remove `package-lock.json` in your project.
- Clean the npm cache by deleting the `npm-cache` folder manually. On Windows it is by default on `%appdata%\npm-cache` location. As an alternative `npm cache clean --force` command could also work, but if you want to be sure, do the manual delete.

In your case most probably the last step is missing, the cleaning of the npm cache. If the npm cache is not cleaned, `npm install` gets the already downloaded packages from the cache and writes their registry url into the newly generated `package-lock.json`. And as the cached packages are still from `https://company.jfrog.io`, the urls in the generated `package-lock.json` will still point to `https://company.jfrog.io`.

Comment: I didn't delete node_modules. That caught me out. thanks very much!