# npm install not working , getting ERROR cb() never called

Tags: angular

```
npm install -g @angular/cli

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-04T10_40_16_051Z-debug.log
```

Tried

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Also, checked the proxy as i am behind corporate proxy . Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Is this only related to angular? Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called

Comment: Try deleting package-lock and then clean cache and try again

Comment: @Tejeshree Even for npm install -g @angular/cli i am getting this error , so technically might not be issue with package-lock