# npm ERR cb() coming up while npm i

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I am getting error while doing npm i in  react project.

nom ERR! cb() never called!

tried every possible options but nothing helps if someone could help?

I tried all the possible options available on google.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a thread with the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called). Have you looked through here? What do you mean you tried everything on Google? In the future don't say this. Instead say what exactly you have tried. The more detail you offer in the question, the easier it will be for someone to help. Currently there is no way to tell what you have tried so the only help I can offer is a thread with the same issue you have.

Comment: I did use “npm cache clean —force” , “npm cache verify” delete package-lock.json still issue coming up.  Got a new HVD allocated installed all the softwares freshly still the same no luck.

Comment: Can someone please suggest for the above issue