# "cb() never called!" - very persistent, tried to solve it using conventional techniques, hasn't worked

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install

When I try to "npm install" my project, it always results in a "cb() never called!". I'm using the 6.14.13 version of npm and 14.17.0 version of node.

I've tried running this command on a different machine- works there. I've also tried...

1. Running "npm cache clean --force" "npm cache verify"
2. Deleting node_modules folder
3. Completely uninstalling and reinstalling node
4. Combining steps 1-3

It resolved itself for about 12 hours one time, even though I hadn't changed anything. (I ran it once, it failed, ran it again about 60 seconds later, and it worked). I also tried cloning the repository into another folder. This hadn't worked previously, but as of this morning, it does now for some reason.

I'm very confused. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this may be due to your package-lock.json being corrupted.
Have you tried:

- deleting package-lock.json
- then running: `npm cache clean --force`
- then running: `npm install`

source: https://reactgo.com/npm-err-cb-never-called/

This old SO post has some more ideas you could try: [npm ERR cb() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called)